# What gaming servers can I run on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: server

This is a real simple yet pretty difficult question to answer.

I was wondering what gaming server ports are there that can run on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I is interesting how this question has 12k views (at time of writing) but also I keep getting down votes and no comment to why? :D I know the answers are not what you may expect but it answers a good question (IMHO) in a satisfactory way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a list of known gaming **servers** that run and are supported by the the Raspberry Pi

- [Minecraft: Pi Edition](http://pi.minecraft.net/) <sup>† *</sup>
- [OpenArena Server](http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/openarena?adult) <sup>†</sup>
- [OpenTTD](http://www.openttd.org/en/) <sup>† *</sup>
- [Freeciv](http://thenated0g.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/raspberry-pi-freeciv-server-install/) <sup>† *</sup>

<sup>†Stable in wheezy</sup>

<sup>*Latest version requires jessie</sup>

**How to use jessie packages without a full upgrade**

Jessie is on its way and was added to the Pi repo in July 2013. You can install game servers by adding the jessie repo and only updating packages that are needed to run with the server.

Comment: Anything that is in the Raspbian Repositories can probably be "run". Whether they can be of any use is a different matter though.

Comment: Like what? I cannot find anything by searching the inter web. Any suggestion

Comment: Just a guess, since I'm not at home, but OpenArena would probably have a dedicated server in the Repos. Nexuiz, Tremulous

Answer (score 3):

Download and write [Quake on LAN](http://www.quakeonlan.net/) to an SD Card. Endless fun, just works.

Answer (score 2):

You could grep the games package list for servers:

```
wget -q -O- http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/65-raspbian-games | grep -i server
```

Truncated output:

```
0.2.8.3.2-1 dedicated game server for Armagetron Advanced</li>
<h3>blobby-server</h3>
1.0~rc1-2 Volleyball game with blobs (server)</li>
<h3>bzflag-server</h3>
2.0.16.20100405+nmu1 bzfs - BZFlag game server</li>
1.70.0-1 Architecture independent common files for Crossfire server</li>
<h3>darkplaces-server</h3>
0~20110628+svn11619-3 Standalone server for Quake-based games</li>
<h3>freeciv-server</h3>
2.3.2-1 Civilization turn based strategy game (server files)</li>
```

Though you could probably get many others working purely from source.

Comment: Obvious to many but not to me. That did help me find allot of game servers. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is an obvious route of enquiry, the site I wget from isn't an offical Raspberry Pi project site, so I can't guarantee that it's totally up to date. Perhaps a sudo apt-get update and using aptitude to search a fresh local copy would be better.

Comment: Either way it helped me find some interesting projects that I will enjoying playing and hosting on my Pi... if they work :) Its all about trying it out.

Comment: Indeed, remember if there's a game you do find which is not in this list, perhaps you could port it's server component from source.

Comment: You make it sound easy to port? It involves compiling it with special flags and changing source sometimes does it not? I have limited experience with that.

Comment: Since Raspbian is based on Debian, any porting work for this sort of thing should be fairly minimal. Game servers are simple beasts in comparison to actual games.

Comment: I tried a few game servers and it seems they are in the Pi repo but mostly outdated versions. Trying to get the latest versions to work I used the debian repo with armh binaries and updated the packages but got `segmentation fault` while trying to install some libraries. Had to reload debian as everything went tits up :( Is there a way to make a jail in Debian?

Comment: Hmm, I'd need more information about what you did and what happened to cause the segfault. [Jails](https://wiki.debian.org/Debian_GNU/kFreeBSD/Jails) are possible under debian [Create a debian chroot jail for testing](http://larig.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/create-a-debian-chroot-jail-for-testing/)

Comment: OK What I have done now is used the raspbian repo of jessie and pinned it lower priority. I am installing openttd using the  `-t jessie` repo though to keep wheezy intact for now. `libc6` now prompts me that services will be restarted. Everything installs just fine and dandy now! So I am running wheezy with some updated libs from jessie.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the rpi to create a QuakeWorld server as well

1. Download nQuakesv (linux server version) from http://nquake.com/;
2. Use the script to download and install everything. answer no to both "QTV" and "QWFWD" - no binaries yet for rpi;
3. go to nquakesv / folder and backup mvdsv and ktx/qwprogs.so (rename)
4. download the raspberry pi binaries of these files from here: https://mega.co.nz/#!mhY3DIjJ!BxHv40BeIzkPMw0T0LAZD16ll0xaYliNaptE-LJIII0
5. give +x permissions to mvdsv (its called the multiview server and replaces the old qwsv binary);
6. to start your server, type ./run/port1.sh

voilà! the server has started in 28501 port.

refer to www.quakeworld.nu for help

Answer (score 0):

You can also start a WindWard Server. the Server File for Windward ist in the Game instaall folder.

Take a look here for a more Informations:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/326410/discussions/0/618458030658786920/